# Facebook PIXEL not Working in the landing page, Advanced matching

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel

The Facebook Pixel was installed on the landing page but the email data was not sent, just the phone number and name

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gugdz.png)

Manual installation was done, I can only install Facebook manually but I need to track it through Pixel email and it simply doesn't work

Comment: Is email address on the page when the pixel fired? Advanced matching does it's best to find things, but manual matching is probably more accurate.